# How to send audio data to Icecast with proper timing?

Tags: java, audio, mp3, shoutcast, icecast

I am writing an `Icecast` source. The source handles `MP3` at the moment. The application can parse `MP3` files to retrieve individual frames and other `metadata`. The application correctly sends `metadata` to the `Icecast` server.

The issue arises when the application attempts to send the `MP3` `frames` to `Icecast`. It sends the `frames` too fast, causing **skips** in the audio when I listen via my media client (`VLC`).

I have read that `Icecast` does not handle the timing of the audio stream and that this is the source's job. I can determine the duration of the audio file and all the information regarding each frame.

**How do I perform proper timing?** Should I wait in between sending individual frames, batches of frames? What does the timing actually consist of?

One method I have attempted, is to cause the application to wait in between sending batches of frames, however this did not fix the timing issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must send your audio data at the sample rate of the stream.  The timing you must use is the timing of the playback rate.  If you want your source stream to be 44.1kHz, you must send that data at 44.1kHz.

MP3 frame sizes are fixed at 1,152 samples.  That means that if you are sending a stream at 44.1kHz, you must send 38.28125 frames per second to Icecast.  I suggest having a large buffer on your source end so that you can decode at whatever rate is reasonable, and have another thread for keeping the timing when sending the data.

Comment: Is it fine if I round it to 38 (in terms of quality), or am I supposed to send a partial frame?

Comment: @noahnu Don't think of it as trying to fit within one second... computers don't really care what a second is.  Send your frames one by one, as close to the correct rate as possible.  You should have a regular loop in your thread that checks the RTC time, and a frame count.  If you're a frame behind, send a frame.  If you're three frames behind, send three frames.  Downstream buffers will work themselves out, but do stick to the correct sample rate as closely as possible.  Rounding isn't allowed, but some jitter is.